# maintaining carriage returns from a mysql entry

Tags: php

How can i  maintain the description of a product as i can see it in the mysql database which includes the carriage returns e.t.c but no HTML.

Is there a function in PHP which can interpret the bits required so when it renders it has 
 or

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTMl doesn't honour carriage returns. PHP has the [`nl2br`](http://php.net/nl2br) function to insert `<br />` tags where carriage returns are present.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers!  Easier than expected!

Comment: Don't forget to Accept the answer that you found the most useful!

Comment: Can i go one step further and create a <br> tag within the function?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: Instead of it being just a carriage return could it add a opening and closing p tag for example?  Between one carriage return and the next?

Comment: Ah, OK. Not with `nl2br`.  Check out the `wpautop` function at http://trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/formatting.php for how you could set that sort of thing up.

Answer (score 1):

nl2br(), described here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

This function converts the newline character into `<br />` tags.  This preserves newlines visually in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you probably want to use this function:

```
$text_to_display = nl2br($text_from_database);
```

This will add a **br** tag before all newlines, so it will show up as line breaks in the html output.